# Removing Sortable Jquery Tabs Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-tabs

I have put together a demo of the issue.

Basically the wrong tab is removed after sorting. Not all sorting creates the problem so follow my example in the JSFiddle JavaScript section. I have two examples of funny business:

http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/ (rather long demo)

http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/7/ (considerably shortened)

http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/13/ (Same as 7 (above) but removes tab using the href)

Both show different problems.

These have been an issue for ages now and I see the issue in the upcoming 1.9 release too.

So if anyone can help resolve this, I'd be much appreciated.

p.s. I made a post at the jquery forum too.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-tabs-wrong-tab-removed-after-sorting

Comment: Some weird things going on... addTabRemoveEvent is called twice but tabs.remove is only called once on the double delete.. Might work if you use that to delete the tab or?

Comment: Sorry, addTabRemoveEvent is called twice??? Elaborate please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, the issue is that the tab is successfully being sorted but the tab panel is not. The answer therefore is to update the panel to mirror the same position as its corresponding tab.

Thanks to Ajay for working this out in the previous post. The updated example can be seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/23/

Note the addTabSortableEvent functions update method.

Comment: Sorry - the only reason was your main answer was not that close to the actual problem. But I did up your comment! Another time my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the event was getting fired multiple times, so I added basic check. You can also implement check based on number of tabs.

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/1/.

Note that the I removed some of the code to ease the debugging.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you and interesting... The final tab panel is not being removed in this instance?

Comment: Just had a fiddle with yours (no pun) and the hiding of the tab makes you think the tab is being removed. I've removed the hide and the tabs can no longer be removed. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/5/

Comment: well in that case, u dont need any check for event progressions. Also note that its still a hack...

Comment: Removing the event makes it works, but leads to more wired behavior

Comment: Thanks for your time Ajay - I've been stuck on this for months (on and off). I believe its a bug that has been visited before but is not fixed. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4524

Comment: There is issue with jQuery handling removing the tabs. It just removing the child content based on index and not on "id". They might have their own reason to do so. As a alternative, you can try implementing sort update event, and rearrange div based on updated position of tabs (li).

Comment: Hi Ajay- You can also use the tab "href" to remove the tabs but you still get the same issue. http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/13/

Comment: I captured "update" event of sort and rearranged the child divs, now it is working http://jsfiddle.net/GM9BQ/22/, You need to change the logic which generates new id.

Comment: I see, you're moving the panel along with the tab to keep them in line. Makes sense I guess. Nice one.